# System.Design cannot be referenced in Class Library?

Tags: .net, reference, system.drawing

I have a very strange problem that I cannot fix and don't know what's going on... I am using VS 2010 Premium and .NET 4.0.

Here are my steps to simulate the problem.

---

Step 1. Create a new VB class library project named "MyClassLib"

Step 2. Create a new class named "MyTestingClass".

```
Public Class MyTestingClass
    Inherits System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(GetType(List(Of String)))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Step 3. Add two .net reference. "System.Design" and "System.Drawing".

Step 4. Create a new VB console application named "MyClassExe"

Step 5. Add "MyClassLib" reference to "MyClassExe".

Step 6. Open Module1.vb in "MyClassExe" project

Step 7. In the Main method, type

```
Dim a = New MyClassLib.MyTestingClass()
```

Step 8. Try to compile "MyClassLib". It doesn't have problem.

Step 9. Try to compile "MyClassExe". It cannot compile because the WHOLE MyClassLib cannot be found!!!

---

I have no idea what's going on?

Moreover, the same case happens in C#.

Does anyone know what's the problem with "System.Design"?

Thank!!!

Comment: The type or namespace name 'MyClassLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Design in the Console Project.

You cannot use a class if it inherits a class in an assembly that you didn't reference.

Comment: Cannot add System.Design to the console project. In the .net reference list, there is no System.Design assembly. I also tried to add `<Reference Include="System.Design" />` in the project file directly, it also doesn't work.

Comment: oooo really thanks!!!! Problem solved!!! But why the default framework is ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"?

Comment: @Alex: It's a smaller install for your end-users.  It's also being pushed via Windows Update.

Comment: @SLake: thx! I found the related information here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx